# Help me find movie / series - ends with the story becoming a tattoo

Tags: story-identification

I saw this thing when I was pretty young, so before 1995 I believe. I hope the years haven't fuddled my memory, but I haven't been able to locate any reference to this anywhere. I've tried googling on several occasions before.

It was a sci-fi story on an alien planet. There were people amongst a maze-like mountain range with fake prop looking rocks. They were very thirsty and did not have any water. However, there were several small streams of water (or liquid) running down the rocks and they knew the water to be poisonous. In the end at least one of them succumbs to drinking the water while another watches and tries to persuade him not to.

However, after the story ends, the final scene fades out and appears as a tattoo on a man whose body is covered with tattoos. This man is living in our times and was outside by a fire, or something similar. This was the end of the episode or movie, with the text coming in after.

I got the impression that this might have been a television series where each episode was a story about a tattoo some man had, or that each story appeared on the mans body as a tattoo - however, after seeing just that one thing, I do not know for sure.

Does anybody have any idea what this might be?

Comment: see also https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/223515/old-story-about-a-man-with-tattoos-that-told-stories (about the collection on which the this was based)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is [**The Illustrated Man**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Illustrated_Man_(film)) by Ray Bradbury. It was made into a film in 1969.

The eponymous character tells a series of science fiction stories based on his various tattoos. None of them seems an especially good match to your story though.

Comment: That's it, I am certain! Apparently the planet with the rocks was actually a jungle, and there was a crashed starship, and there was heavy rain. It's shown in the trailer!

Comment: The story I was remembering seems to be "The Long Rain".

Comment: Oh, it could be instead that what I saw was an episode of "The Ray Bradbury Theater", which also had "The Long Rain" as an episode.